# antiderivative of $f(x)=(3x^2-1)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

It is easy to calculate $\int(3x^2-1)^2dx$: $\int(3x^2-1)^2dx=9x^4-6x^2+1dx=\frac{9}{5}x^5-2x^3+x+c$ $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now, one of my friends calculated the antiderivative of f with a similar method to subsitution, but which I have never seen before and which I don't understand, he named this method "backwards subsitution".
He get $F(x)=\frac{1}{3}(3x^2-1)^3\frac{1}{6x}$ as an antiderivative of f.
It is $F'=f$, but x has to be nonzero. It seems to be a different result as $\frac{9}{5}x^5-2x^3+x$, but I don't understand what is wrong. Is $F(x)=\frac{1}{3}(3x^2-1)^3\frac{1}{6x}$ an antiderivative of f?
Regards

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=antiderivative+of+%283x%5E2-1%29%5E2

Comment: $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$ if $F'(x) = f(x)$. But $F'(x) = \frac{(3x^2-1)^2(15x^2+1)}{18x^2}$, which is clearly not $f(x)$

Comment: Your friend's method only works when a function's argument is a linear polynomial in x but not in case of a quadratic.

Comment: @Brenton oh, I forgot to use the product rule. Thank you! @A Googler, thanks!Good to know!

Answer (score 3):

One fundamental principle in calculus is that you don't (or your friend doesn't) get to make up new rules and expect them to work. His method is incorrect and doesn't follow at all from the rule of substitution.